# jquery ajax call not executing alert inside function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have no idea why this does not work:

```
$.get("/some/url/", function(event) {
    alert('hey');
});
```

I can see the response get executed in the console in Firefox when I click the button, and I can see it succeeded (200 OK). I can also see the response from the web server is correct... so why doesn't the alert inside the function call work? The alert works outside the function call.

Here is the whole block for context:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#some_id").click(function(event) {
            $.get("/some/url/", function(data) {
               alert('hey');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using Django if that makes a difference.

**EDIT:**
I have since changed my view from an HTTPResponse to JSONResponse and now the ajax call doesn't fail and I can throw the alert. Thanks to everyone who suggested a type issue, still not sure why HTTPResponse would deliver the object but the ajax call would consider that a "failure". Special thanks to  Miguel Lattuada and  JRodDynamite for helping me get on the right track.

**EDIT2:**
For those curious, my view (Django) was returning this:

```
return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

and I changed it to this:

```
return  JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

That seemed to make ajax happy for some reason and cause the success function call to succeed.

Comment: How about `console.log('hey');`? Does your console log anything? Another possibility is that what you see as `200` might be a different url, not the ajax you are looking at.

Comment: Is the element with id `some_id` added dynamically to your DOM?

Comment: @Teemu The click handler works fine, that's not the issue.

Comment: @ShangWang No, it doesn't log anything. If I move the alert or the console.log outside of the ajax call, they both behave correctly (i.e. alerting, logging to console)

Comment: @Teemu the only thing different is the urls. Everything else is copied verbatim.

Comment: Well, that handler is definitely not being attached if that's your code.

Comment: @Teemu this is just the script block... I don't need to post the whole html here. If that is what is confusing you.

Comment: @Teemu I'm confused. Are you referring to the anonymous function passed as the argument to `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @MinusFour I think everyone is getting hung up on the fact that there isn't the whole html page template here... that isn't needed to answer this issue so I didn't post it.

Comment: Ah, @Stryner, now i see it. Then maybe it's an error being triggered before it reaches that line.

Comment: If `some_id` is a submit button, then you need `$("#some_id").click(function( event ) { event.preventDefault();` - note a button without a type is a submit

Comment: That's simple, what you need to be called to see the alert is the success function. You are getting an error. Add .fail(function(err)... to see what is happening...

Comment: @MiguelLattuada I added a fail function (apparently there is something causing it to fail, good suggestion). However, the response is actually the object I was expecting and not an exception. So, perhaps the suggestions about datatype were correct? Here is the object I got back, minus sensitive data:  Object { readyState=4,  responseText="{'blah': u'blahblah', 'blahnum': 123}{'blah2': u'blahblah', 'blahnum2': 30}" status=200...... the view I created is supposed to be passing back a json object. From the view: return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json') httprequest object?

Comment: Well, that's not not a valid JSON: `{'blah': u'blahblah', 'blahnum': 123}{'blah2': u'blahblah', 'blahnum2': 30}`.

Comment: @MinusFour the actual response text from the object validates with jsonlint... my "de-identified" result isn't. I believe the object I am getting back is a httprequest object that has json in it's response text field. Not sure why that would trigger a fail for the ajax call but it does.

Comment: The first argument to the `fail` handler isn't error, it's a jqXHR object. The actual error thrown is the third argument: `fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){})`

Comment: @MinusFour ahh, I didn't know that. Thanks for your help on this. If I need to debug ajax calls in the future I will remember that. I have since switched my view to returning a jasonresponse object instead of an http one and it seems to make the ajax call happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you submit your page.

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#some_id").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event - not needed on type=button though
    $.get("/some/url/", function(data) {
       window.console&&console.log('hey');
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="some_id">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

this assumes the return value from /some/url/ is valid object - the console should tell you

Comment: Yeah, it seems that something about my object is causing the response to trigger a fail.. even though I actually get an object back.

Answer (score 0):

The result is probably not in JSON format, so when jQuery tries to parse it as such, it fails. Try validating the JSON.

If the response is not in JSON format then try specifying the datatype. If it is returning a simple text then specify `text`.

```
$.get("/some/url/", function(data) {
    alert('hey');
}, "text");
```

Comment: Bad... 
dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).

Comment: Datatype passed back from the server is in fact Json (confirmed from the browser). I'm just trying to get a simple alert to happen within the function block. I'm not sure this is the issue.

Comment: @user2540074 - Try validating the JSON object it returns. Use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON object.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro I believe I am actually dealing with a httprequest object and not Json directly. The response text is json but the object coming back is wrapped around the json. The response text actually validates with lint.

Comment: @user2540074 - What exactly is your view returning? It should return a `HttpResponse` object or a `JsonResponse` object. You should **not** return a `HttpRequest` object. Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/views/#writing-views).

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro The view is returning an HttpResponse, so I would assume it is that.

Comment: @user2540074 - Could you post the code of the view in the question?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro I have since edited the issue with my fix. Thanks so much for your help on this, I credited you in the edit directly. Changing the view return type made the difference. Not sure why the HttpResponse object was triggering the failure function of the ajax call but it is happy now. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2540074 - Glad I could help out. Btw were you passing any model class objects into `HttpResponse` object? Maybe you didn't serialize those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Promise mechanism:

```
$.get("/some/url/").done(function() {
    alert( "1" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "2" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "3" );
  });
```

Also, you can use $.ajax() function to test if connection is correct

Comment: Yeah, it triggers the fail but a console.log on the .fail function displays the object I am expecting back. Httprequest object wrapped around a json response. Not sure why that would trigger a fail.

Comment: does request url is the same domain as website? Maybe you have cross origin request, and you have to use JSONP?

Comment: I got it to work. Apparently, the ajax request didn't like the HttpResponse object for some reason and it triggered the .fail function. I have since edited my view to return a JSONResponse object and the ajax call is now happy (my edit above). Thanks for the help man!